# paired t-test with a seasonality

Tags: hypothesis-testing, seasonality

I'm trying to test the hypothesis of whether a certain improvement of the product will affect the consumption of the products.

I have a group of test subjects and I measured each test subject's consumption level before and after the product improvements(time series for each subject). But if the consumption level is related to the season, say month of the year, how can I test the hypothesis? Paired t-test doesn't seem to address the seasonality issue here.

Comment: Do you have the information necessary to test seasonality, i.e., monthly data for a minimum of two years?

Comment: Yes, the seasonality is definitely there. We have historical consumption level data tracing back years. But not the ones of the test subjects. Also the average consumption level of each subject may vary but all of them have seasonality.

Comment: Ok...but does that answer my question? My point is that you can't integrate and test seasonality without a time series. Of course, you can make pro forma or swag assumptions about seasonal consumer behavior and extrapolate on that, but that's not what you're asking.

Comment: I see. So if we don't have time series long enough to test seasonality for the test subjects but we know from other subjects(same demography) that the consumption level is influenced by the season. How can I achieve what I asked, test whether the product improvement is effective?

Comment: That's the point, what empirical information would the test be based on? In the absence of that, a test of significance for seasonality isn't possible. Why not just step back from a formal test and rely on your assumptions, intuition, judgement and the other things that have convinced you that seasonality is present? For many marketers, that's sufficient.